# How to force account login for a single account user with Google's OAuth 2.0?

Tags: oauth-2.0, owin, google-oauth

Sometimes when a user logins into a site with Google's OAuth 2.0 they choose the wrong account to login with.  Normally this isn't a problem if the user has more than one account registered with the browser, google will automatically show the user select screen:
[image: user selection screen]

But if a user has only one account and is logged in, this screen is skipped.  Instead I need Google's sign in panel to always appear, so that I can be sure the user has the option to try and enter the correct account.   I tried using `approval_prompt = "force"`, but that forces the acceptance of permissions rather than simply showing the login page.
[image: Google's one user login]
**How can I force Google's OAuth 2.0 to always show the login screen?**
(and never automatically skip it)

Comment: The accepted answer below only shows the account chooser and doesn't actually force the user to log in, did you ever find an actual solution?

Comment: @blented - Sorry the "prompt=select_account" did what I needed, I think there might be separate way to force login.  But then again, that's on google's side so they may decide its not necessary in some situations.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add the parameter `prompt=select_account` to your authorization request.

This will cause the account chooser to always be shown, even if the user is only logged in to one account. Users will be able to select from their accounts, or add a new one.

For example: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Foauthplayground&response_type=code&client_id=407408718192.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=profile+email&access_type=offline&prompt=select_account

Comment: @William: Dose you technique will work on Hybrid mobile app?