# How to make Google stop logging user in automatically in PassportJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth, google-oauth, passport.js

I am only allowing users to log in with a certain domain name. This specific functionality works and is not the root of the problem. The problem is that users get stuck in a sort of negative feedback loop when they attempt to log in with an incorrect email address.

[image: Image describing the login process visually]

In reference to the picture above, a user (in a blank incognito page with no information) starts at step one. Clicking login brings them to step two and then to step 3. Attempting to log in with an email address ending with an incorrect domain brings them to step 4. This is desired.

After step four, if they log out of the website, they are presented with step one. Which is desirable. The code for logging out is as follows.

```
app.get("/logout", function(req, res) {
    req.logout()
    req.session.destroy()
    res.clearCookie("connect.sid")
    res.redirect("/")
})
```

What happens after they click login **again** is what is undesirable. Instead of bringing them back to step 2 (desired, so they can log in again with their CORRECT email address), it brings them **straight to step four.** It is as if Google is remembering who logged in last.

Here is the [code for my passport.js configuration file](https://github.com/Connorelsea/LSMSA-SGO-Website/blob/master/config/passport.js).

**Short Question:** How can I signal to Google not to do this? Or trigger the browser to allow them to log in again? I am at a loss.

**Extra Details:** In the [Oauth2.0 Documentation for Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect), it mentions hd and realm, which can restrict logins to a certain domain. But I do not know how I would configure this in the PassportJS configuration file.

Comment: Kinda feel like google shouldn't be not doing this. If the user is logged in, it shouldn't ask them to login again. The real problem here is that the email address you are getting back from the user isn't always the same, so if they change which account they're logged in under and go to your app, they'll be sent to step 4. Not entirely sure what to suggest.

Comment: My code on github is linked in the question. Do you think you could take a look? I've been researching this for almost a week now and cannot figure this out. It seems as if, since the user has already authenticated and logged into Google, it is simply not asking them to log in again and is logging them in automatically when Google is asked for authentication. I don't know what to do in this situation. How would you design this system?

Comment: Like this has to be common. What if a user in another app wanted to log out and then log back in with a different email, but still using Google authentication in the same browser. I do not know how to accomplish this.

Comment: It's not going to be very common, because it isn't common to restrict access based on email address domain.

Comment: That is why I brought up another situation that may happen. If someone wants to change their email address are they just screwed?

Comment: I wouldn't use oauth in a case where i needed to restrict to only users who have access to an email address on a specific domain, because, the user very well could change their email address on google and still be "logged in" to your system without your system knowing that the address changed.

Comment: Basically, you need to have your system only care about the domain of the email address at registration. After that point, it should just go off of the profile id.

Comment: I appreciate your help a lot, but I am not sure what you are saying in that last comment. Would that be using Passport and OAuth, or would I have to implement something else.

Comment: I'm reading the readme here: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth

Comment: You seem to already be doing it correctly, so, why is it sending the user to step 4?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84119/discussion-between-kevin-b-and-connorelsea).

Comment: My 2¢ worth is that it's definitely a Google problem. Google needs to fix this in their own implementation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think what you want is to prompt the user to select their account. Similar situation to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31544595/72176) which I answered. This way the users will clearly choose which account they wish to use, even if they have already signed in before.

---

Add the parameter `prompt=select_account` to your authorization request.

```
app.get(
    "/auth/google",
    passport.authenticate(
        "google",
        {
            scope : ["profile", "email"],
            prompt : "select_account" // Added here
        }
    )
)
```

This will cause the account chooser to always be shown, even if the user is only logged in to one account. Users will be able to select from their accounts, or add a new one.

For example: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Foauthplayground&response_type=code&client_id=407408718192.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=profile+email&access_type=offline&prompt=select_account

---

Also, if you wish to restrict access based on a domain, and that domain is a Google Apps for Work domain, the most correct way to do this is to inspect the `hd` param in the ID Token. [How to process the ID Token](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth), and extract the `hd` claim.

Comment: I think that's the correct answer and I upvoted it (thanks for the tip about the `prompt` parameter). I'm going to leave my answer thought, as a reference in case someone wants to revoke their token.

Comment: How do I add this parameter in node? I did it like this and it does not seem to be working. https://gist.github.com/Connorelsea/162f1e3d27b0440bff06

Comment: And I am inspecting the domain after they are authenticated, and it is working, but it results in the user not being able to log in again unless they already have multiple accounts liked to their google account. Google just logs them in automatically.

Comment: What I want to do is have them presented with step 2 after they logout, instead of being presented with step 4. If that makes sense.

Comment: Holy crap! I added it to the right place and it works. Thank you both, William and simo, so much for the help. I've been trying to solve this for over a week now.

Comment: Awesome! Glad it works, and thanks for editing the answer to include the Node.js specific instructions.

Answer (score 1):

You can [revoke](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke) the token on your end if you're not satisfied with the email used. You have to make one additional request to revoke the access token for that account to your OAuth app.

In your route callback execute this code (example using the `request` module):

```
request.get('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke', {
  qs:{token:'[ACCESS or REFRESH TOKEN]'}
}, function (err, res, body) {

})
```

After that the user will be prompted again on subsequent login attempt.

Take a look at @William Denniss's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31605026/1260020) as well, if you want to be prompted each time for a user login.

Comment: Both of these answers are extremely helpful. Thank you both very much.