# How to show google accounts screen after authentication in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, google-signin

I need to show the user Google Login screen every time even after authentication by using GoogleSignIn SDK for iOS.

I have to integrate Google SignIn in my iOS application. For which I followed https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating and with this, I was able to successfully log in.

I found some input on this by researching that we can do this by directly calling that Google OAuth Authentication URL by appending one parameter as {prompt=select_account}. Link for this [How to force account login for a single account user with Google's OAuth 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31544595/how-to-force-account-login-for-a-single-account-user-with-googles-oauth-2-0)

But I want to do this same by using Google Sign In SDK. Is there is any way of doing this?

```
[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].clientID = @"CLIENT_ID";

[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].delegate = self;

 [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].uiDelegate = self;

 [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signIn];
```

Answer (score 0):

The hack is to call signout before signin,which will allow you to show Google  login screen every time. But it's not a reliable solution i think. If you find anything new please update. Thanks

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.signOut()
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.signIn()
```